# Validation Close date greater than 30 days and stage is 'won'

Tags: validation, validation-rule

When closing an opportunity (won) I would like to get an error if close date is NOT greater than 30 days

It does not seems to be working, when I try to save the record it save successfully even though my close date is not greater than 30 days.

Any ideas?

```
AND(
OR (
 ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Won")
),
CloseDate > TODAY() + 30)
)
```

Comment: You say "I would like to get an error if close date is greater than 30 days" but also "[the record] save successfully even though my close date is not greater than 30 days." Those appear to be opposite of one another. Can you please [edit] to clarify?

Comment: This formula is also not valid - the parentheses are not balanced. Please share viable code.

Comment: sorry typo I meant if the close date is not greater than 30 days, update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula should evaluate to true to give an error. So ideally, you should check if the CloseDate<Today() +30

Also you don't need the OR condition.

See below formula:

```
AND(
 ISCHANGED(StageName),
 ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Won"),
 CloseDate < TODAY() + 30
)
```

Comment: Also worth noting that this will block _all edits_ to Closed Won opps, which is probably not what is actually desired (if not stated!) I would add an ISCHANGED() check.

Comment: Agreed, so added a ISCHANGED() check only for Stage as of now(for example). But would also depend on how future edits need to be handled, if edit to Closed Won opportunities are allowed. Accordingly ClosedDate/ModifiedDate needs to be checked